# can python 2.7 be removed completely now?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am on ubuntu 15.10. I notice that i have many python versions installed. Is it safe now to remove 2.7 completely? And how to make 3.5 the default one? I ask this because i think it messes up my django installation because django gets intsalled in share directory.

Comment: Python3.5 won't help since you can't use psycopg2 with it (if you use postgres), you should ask about the problems you're having with your django installation instead of whether or not you should delete python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

A lot of application still require Python 2.7 and are not yet compatible with Python3. So it really depends on what you do on the server (Only running Django?).

One solution would be to use `virtualenv` so that you do not depend on which python version is installed in your server, and you totally control all the packages.

Look for django + virtualenv, you will find a lot of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dric512; it's definitely a best practice to run Django applications in a virtualenv. The commands to get Django going would be:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-virtualenv
mkdir new-django-project && cd new-django-project
virtualenv --python python3.5 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install django
```

Whenever your command prompt starts with (venv), you'll be using python 3. You can also verify that with `which python` or `which pip`; this will show you that you are using the python virtual environment in your venv directory instead of the system global python setup in /usr.

#### Option 2

Another option is using update-alternatives to set the default python:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

This should give you a menu allowing you to choose the default python.

#### Option 3

A final (riskier) way to make python 3.5 the default is to run

```
ls -l $(which python)
```

This should give you something like

```
/usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

If that's the case, then you can change the symlink to 3.5 with

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
```